# ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712

Tags: wso2-api-manager

There was two similar question in stackoverflow but cloud't help me to solve the probelm.
I want to use loadbalancing for two nodes of wso2 api manager 3.2.0 using Nginx. I configured api manager as following :
could you please guide me?

```
[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443

[server]
hostname = "api.am.wso2.com"

node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
#offset=0
mode = "single" #single or ha

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"


[apim.throttling]
event_duplicate_url = ["tcp://172.24.64.115:5673"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://172.24.64.114:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://172.24.64.114:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://172.24.64.115:9612"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://172.24.64.115:9712"]
type = "loadbalance"
[apim.analytics]
enable = true
store_api_url = "https://localhost:7444"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
event_publisher_type = "default"
event_publisher_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher"
publish_response_size = true

 [[apim.analytics.url_group]]
analytics_url =["tcp://172.25.129.69:7611","tcp://172.25.129.70:7611"]
analytics_auth_url =["ssl://172.25.129.69:7711","ssl://172.25.129.70:7711"]
type = "loadbalance"



#[[apim.analytics.url_group]]
#analytics_url =["tcp://analytics1:7612","tcp://analytics2:7612"]
#analytics_auth_url =["ssl://analytics1:7712","ssl://analytics2:7712"]
#type = "failover"
.
```

While ruuning wso2server.sh faced following exception :

```
    StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/keymanager-operations].File[/opt/v1/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/keymanager-operations.war]
    [2021-07-28 16:29:32,729]  WARN - DataEndpointGroup No receiver is reachable at reconnection, will try to reconnect every 30 sec
    [2021-07-28 16:29:32,732] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
    org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
            at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:147) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.26.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.26.jar:?]
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_291]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_291]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_291]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_291]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_291]
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7712
            at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:81) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.26.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.26.jar:?]
            at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212) ~[commons-pool_1.5.6.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.26.jar:?]
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7712
            at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:273) ~[libthrift_0.12.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:173) ~[libthrift_0.12.0.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:64) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.26.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.26.jar:?]
            at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212) ~[commons-pool_1.5.6.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.26.jar:?]
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
```

Server (69) & Server(70) as following:

```
  # Carbon Configuration Parameters
wso2.carbon:
  type: wso2-apim-analytics
    # value to uniquely identify a server
  id: wso2-am-analytics
    # server name
  name: WSO2 API Manager Analytics Server
    # ports used by this server
  ports:
      # port offset
    offset: 1

wso2.transport.http:
  transportProperties:
    -
      name: "server.bootstrap.socket.timeout"
      value: 60
    -
      name: "client.bootstrap.socket.timeout"
      value: 60
    -
      name: "latency.metrics.enabled"
      value: true

  -
      # Data receiver configuration
    dataReceiver:
        # Data receiver type
        # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
      type: Thrift
        # Data receiver properties
      properties:
        tcpPort: '7611'
        sslPort: '7711'

  -
      # Data receiver configuration
    dataReceiver:
        # Data receiver type
        # THIS IS A MANDATORY FIELD
      type: Binary
        # Data receiver properties
      properties:
        tcpPort: '9611'
        sslPort: '9711'
        tcpReceiverThreadPoolSize: '100'
        sslReceiverThreadPoolSize: '100'
        hostName: 0.0.0.0
```

Clould you please help me ?

Comment: Can you please share your throttling related config as well?

Comment: I updated question and shared  throttling related config

Comment: Open the api-manager.xml file in repository/conf directory. What is the value in EventHubConfigurations.EventPublisherConfiguration.ReceiverUrlGroup?

Comment: In addition, have you configured Analytics with the API Manager servers? If so, please update the attached TOML configurations reflecting the Analytics segment.

Comment: Thanks. api- manager<ReceiverUrlGroup>tcp://${carbon.local.ip}:${receiver.url.port}</ReceiverUrlGroup>

Comment: when I shutdown analytics, error disappear. I updated analytics segement in question

Comment: could you please help me in this task : @Athiththan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605440/wso2-api-manager-3-2-0-nginx-load-balancing-this-site-can-t-be-reached-error

Comment: could you please help me in this task : @RrR- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605440/wso2-api-manager-3-2-0-nginx-load-balancing-this-site-can-t-be-reached-error

Answer (score 1):

If you have configured the Analytics node with an offset than the default, it is required to configure both `analytics_url` and `analytics_auth_url` under `apim.analytics.url_group` configuration pointing to the correct Hostname and Ports of the Analytics server.

To fail to do so, we can observe the above-mentioned `Connection Refused` error in the API Manager side, as it was trying to communicate with the Analytics and there aren't any ports opened to listen to the communication channel. Therefore, please make sure that you have configured the `analytics_url` and `analytics_auth_url` pointing to the Analytics node in both of your API Manager nodes. You can refer to the following [docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#standard-setup) for instructions.

Comment: Thanks, api gateway runs in 172.24.64.114 and analytics in 172.24.64.116, so I have to configure analytics_url to refer to 172.24.64.116? and what is analytics1 and analytics2 in this config?

Comment: Yes, correct. You have to configure the 172.24.64.116 in the Gateway to publish the events to the Analytics Worker node. The Doc represents the configurations when you are having two Analytics nodes (as analytics1 and analytics2). Since you are having only one Analytics node, you can configure only one set of configurations and ignore the analytics2 set of configurations.