# wso2 api manager 3.2.0 nginx load balancing this site can’t be reached error?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I want to use loadbalancing for wso2 api manager 3.2.0 using Nginx. when call https://localhsot:443 in nginx server,
it redirects to https://api.am.wso2.com/publisher, but can not reach this site error occurs.
could you please me guide, what is wrong?

[image]

Nginx config:

```
  user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;



events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

upstream sslapi.am.wso2.com {
    server 172.24.64.114:9443;
    server 172.24.64.114:9443;
}

upstream sslgw.am.wso2.com {
    server 172.24.64.114:8243;
    server 172.24.64.114:8243;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.am.wso2.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://api.am.wso2.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.am.wso2.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/apimanager.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/apimanager.key;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_send_timeout 5m;
            proxy_pass https://sslapi.am.wso2.com;
        }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name gw.am.wso2.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/apimanager.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/apimanager.key;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_send_timeout 5m;
            proxy_pass https://sslgw.am.wso2.com;
        }

}

}
```

and deployment.toml config in server(172.24.64.114):

```
[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443

[server]
hostname = "api.am.wso2.com"

node_ip = "172.24.64.114"
#offset=0
mode = "single" #single or ha
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"
```

and hosts config in (172.16.11.239) server:

```
172.0.0.1 localhost
172.24.64.114 api.am.wso2.com
```

and hosts config in (172.24.64.114) server:

```
  172.24.64.114    api.am.wso2.com
```

After invoke nginx url (172.24.64.116) it redirects to 172.24.64.114 that is site is not reachable!

[image]

Comment: could please guide me?@Athiththan

Comment: Can you recheck whether your Nginx instance is up and running and has loaded the conf that you have made? Generally, this behavior can be observed when the Nginx is not up and running or the conf that you have created is not loaded properly in your environment.

Comment: You can follow this [Doc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04) to configure the Nginx and starting up

Comment: Thanks. Nginx is up and I followed from doc , but not working

Comment: Please update the `node_ip` configuration to the  `172.24.64.114` and try the scenario.

Comment: Thanks. but problem exist. I updated my question, could you please help me?@Athiththan

Comment: The `hostname` in the TOML configuration should be as `api.am.wso2.com`. Further, in the `/etc/hosts` entry, change the hostname to `api.am.wso2.com`. Then try accessing the portals using `https://api.am.wso2.com/publisher` and share the observations. You may also need a host entry in the `.239` node pointing to the Nginx server with the same hostname.

Comment: Really thanks. I updated  my config & question, but I tried to access portals using https://api.am.wso2.com/publisher and not working with error browser " This site can’t be reached " . also when I invoke nginx with ip (172.24.64.116) the same  error  occure " This site can’t be reached ". could you please help me?I updated question @Athiththan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235553/discussion-between-athiththan-and-tohid-makari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure the API Manager with Proxy Port configurations, it is required to specify a Hostname as well. The same Hostname needs to be configured in the Nginx under `server` configurations. Further, under `upstream`, you have to configure the IP address of the API Manager nodes to direct the requests.

Since you are having a dedicated Nginx server (.116) in the middle, configure the Nginx server's IP address (.116) and the Hostname of the API Manager (`api.am.wso2.com`) in the Client node's (.239) Hosts entry. This will make sure that when you type the Hostname: `api.am.wso2.com` in the Client's node, the request will be dispatched to the Nginx server and then the Nginx will make the communication with the Upstream servers that have been configured.

Try out configuring the Hosts entries correctly in the Client's node and verify the behavior. A sample entry in the Client's Hosts will be as following

```
172.24.64.116 api.am.wso2.com
```

Comment: How to config for gw.am.wso2.com? When I set in client host side of  api.am.wso2.com , then gw.am.wso2.com works for invoke ,but api.am.wso2.com for publisher and devportal not working

Comment: Add the `gw.am.wso2.com` as another Host for the same entry in the Hosts file. This will be as `172.24.64.116 api.am.wso2.com gw.am.wso2.com`. Once the config is done, try invoking the API using the `gw.am.wso2.com` hostname.

Comment: I did befor as you mentioned and invoke api works successfully, but problem occurs for /publisher & /devportal not works after adding  gw.am.wso2.com.

Comment: I set the config of following file to defult, and my problem fixed . /opt/v1/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/public/config/settings.js